# Embedding Cordova WebView on Android

Tags: cordova

i'm using phonegap "2.0" with Android SDK 15, i just want to Embedding Cordova WebView on Android prject, i used step by step the guide [Links](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android), also another example in github [Links](https://github.com/stevengill/CordovaActionView)
my app crashed and stoped automatically when I run.
Logcat error :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
```

my xml file
 "main.xml":

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView android:id="@+id/phoneGapView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout >
```

Thx in advance.. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may have the same error as I did. Once I implemented the methods derived from CordovaInterface in my activity, in particular the getActivity method, the application started just fine.

```
@Override
public Activity getActivity() {
  return this;
}
```

Note that the default implementation returns null while the CordovaWebView most likely requires a proper Activity instance for its initialization.

Note: I am using PhoneGap 2.1.0

Comment: This happened to me when Eclipse auto-generated it.

Comment: It works like charm, Thanks!. Can anybody explain me why does cordova leave these landmines all around for us, the developers, to step in??